# Добрый день! При выполнении данного кода появляются 10 цифр (так и надо) и значение None Как сделать так чтобы значение None НЕ появлялось?

Tags: python

```
from random import*
def rend():
    for i in range(10):
        print(randint(1,10))
rend()
a=rend()
print(a)
```

Comment: Убрать строчку `print(a)`?

Answer (score 3):

Вот так:

```
# a=rend()
# print(a)
```

*PS:* У Вас появляются не десять, а двадцать цифр.

Answer (score 3):

Вы присваиваете переменной `a` значение, возвращаемое функцией `rend`, однако, в функции `rend` у вас нет оператора `return`, следовательно функция ничего не возвращает. Это самое "ничего" обозначается как `None`, которое вы выводите с помощью `print(a)`

Comment: Также пользователь Igor верно подметил, что у вас выводится не 10 чисел, а 20.